# Refresh a Panda dataframe while printing using loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

How can i print a new dataframe and clear the last printed dataframe while using a loop?
So it wont show all dataframes just the last one in the output?

Using print(df, end="\r") doesn't work

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

while True:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
    print(df)
```

If i get live data from an api to insert into the df, i'll use the while loop to constantly update the data. But how can i print only the newest dataframe instead of printing all the dataframes underneath each other in the output?

If i use the snippet below it does work, but i think there should be a more elegant solution.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Height_DF = 10
Width_DF = 10

while True:
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
    print(df)

    for i in range(Height_DF + 1):
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
```

Comment: You have a `while True` loop, it will keep printing the same thing forever. What are you exactly asking?

Comment: Maybe try to add user input as a “pause” ... this quwstion is a little confusing.. try explain what exactly you want?

Comment: If i get live data from an api to print into the df, i'll use the while loop to constantly update the data. But how can i print only the newest dataframe instead of printing all the dataframes underneath each other?

Answer (score 1):

This code allow to "clean" the Jupyter notebook cell, and allow to update/refresh the dataframe:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

while True:
    df = pd.DataFrame(...)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

while True:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
    print(df)
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can regulate the time between prints & clear by changing the sleep constant.

Comment: The sys.stdout.write("\033[F") removes 1 line, so i'll have to copy and paste that 11 times in my code.